# Hardware solutions for enabling 150MB/Second constant speed file writes?

Tags: java, hardware

I am working on a java application and we are IO constrained with our current disc setup.  The performance of the removable RDX discs degrades as they fill until the data write speed < data input speed and data starts having to be discarded.

Just wondering what architecture you would use if you want to be able to process and write data at speeds ~ 150 MB/Second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any SSD would do this. You could also use a RAID set of HDD which would also give you greater capacity. (You would need at least 3-5 to get 150 MB/s depending on your exact hardware)

I suggest you use an SSD to spool the data to it first and then move the data to your RDX as quickly as possible or at least before your SSD fills up.  This would allow you to continue writing data when the removal-able drive is not in place.

In Jun 2018, an 500 GB SSD costs about £110. This would give you about 50 mins of buffer @150 MB/s sustained.

Comment: Given the copy transfer speeds to RDX are less than the write speed to an SSD, could we have multiple RDX drives and be moving files from the SSD to RDX.  Trying to understand the best solution to make sure the SSD never fills up and recording has to stop.